# Choose between multiple "Value if true/false" options

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell which contains a certain iferror function.

In case everything's ok - I want to get the normal output of the function.
However, if there's an error (for example - #N/A), I want that cell to let me choose manuually which text I want to show in that cell - but in case there's another change in the function parameters that causes the original function to become TRUE again, I want the original function back - with its original output.

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible: either a cell's value is determined by a formula, or not. You cannot have both.

What you can do though, is use a nearby cell for that kind of choice (check the dropdown possibility via data validation). Then the `IFERROR` function could read that other cell's value when there is an error condition. If there is no error that other cell's value will obviously be ignored.